# Dual boot using two different SSDs, where the windows one already has a grub loader

Tags: linux, boot, multi-boot, grub, dualboot

I have this problem:

I have an SSD running Windows. Some time ago I did a dual boot using an SD card, putting the /boot partition inside the SSD (ssd0). This worked fine.

Now I bought a new SSD (ssd1) to install Linux, since dual boot with SD is inconvenient.

I am trying to install Linux in the second SSD but I can't.

I tried different distros: Ubuntu, Linux Mint, and Pop!_OS.

None of them work. With Ubuntu and Linux Mint, I could not see the entry in the boot options device, while with Pop!_OS I could, but it was skipped when I set it as the first entry

Here are some photos:

**Pop!_OS Installation**
[image: Pop!_OS installation]

**Boot Devices in Recovery**
[image: Boot Devices in recovery]

As you can see there is the entry, but it is skipped, and Windows boots instead.
The "ubuntu" voice is the GRUB from the previous dual boot with the SD.

Does anyone have a suggestion?
I prefer not to format the whole SSD with Windows if possible.

### EDIT:

I've used boot-repair, as suggested.
The log is here: [log](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/jvqHwtWrRW/)
/dev/sda is the SSD with Windows
/dev/sdb is the SSD where I'd like to install Linux

Thanks to it, I was able to see the "ubuntu (Kingston)" item within the boot menu:

**Boot Menu after have used Boot-repair**
[image: Boot_Ubuntu]

But as before, the boot is skipped.
The second "ubuntu" entry is the former GRUB showing up as such:

**Grub menu from "ubuntu(CT500MX)" voice in the Boot menu**[image: GRUB]

As you can see the second SSD not appear under ls, as it wasn't.

Any suggestion?

### **EDIT2** :

I disabled the fastboot Windows option inside the energy settings and made another round of boot-repair: [Link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gkWf8pRrQX/)

But it gave me the same problem.

Then, I try to re-install POP_OS! with a clean installation inside the second SSD, but still not working.

I don't know if this is useful information: the SSD in which I am trying to install Linux was installed by removing the DVD bay and putting the SSD with the appropriate caddy in its place. Could this be the cause of the problem?

Comment: When installing Linux after Windows in UEFI mode you can, after assuring there's unallocated space, either use the "install alongside" option or choose something else and create at least the root partition in the unallocated space -and- *select* the current EFI partition as such. This assures the correct bootloader is always installed.

Comment: Hi @ChanganAuto Thank you for the answer. I know, in fact that's what I did. I used this feature to install Linux Mint before, and Ubuntu after, on the SSD, but it didn't work...

Comment: Check the option you may or may not no have with boot override. If you can boot successfully adjust boot order / reinstall GRUB. Alternatively you may want to try Boot Repair and, instead of applying the suggested fix, post here the summary report: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thank you for the response. I am trying to do it, at the moment I tried to create a usb device with boot-repair, but in the boot menu it doesn't appear. Now I am trying with ubuntu live and then install boot-repair.

Comment: The 2nd option - live session and then install Boot Repair  - is indeed the recommended method.

Comment: Your boot order has "Linpus lite" first. Just change it to "Ubuntu" in UEFI settings > Boot menu. That *should* be all it needs to boot a working Grub that should already include an entry for Windows as well. If not then make sure you boot "Ubuntu" and then run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: And no, you didn't follow the correct method for installing a Linux distro after Windows with an ESP already in use because somehow you ended up with another ESP in the second drive.

Comment: **And...** When dual-booting with Windows, disabling its Fast Startup feature is a MUST, even before installing Linux because it can and often will prevent writing to the ESP and create all sort of issues. Boot Repair showed a warning about that precisely - *You will have to complete the GRUB setup manually*

Comment: Many Thanks for your reply. 
The "Linpus Lite" entry is the bootable USB into which I put Ubuntu and used it as a live session to run the boot repair tool.
I know I have two ESPs now, since one is in SSD0, where Windows is, and the other is in the other SSD, where I would like to install LInux. But I thought this is not a problem, or maybe it is? I mean, can I use the grub installed in the SSD with Linux, or not?
The problem is that this ESP won't boot...